# After exporting my kivy app, the pictures didnt save

Tags: kivy

i recently made an app with kivy to android apk and i had directions to display pictures, which worked in pycharm, but after putting on android the pictures wont display.  Is there something i am missing?

Comment: welcome to stack overflow please make a clear description for your issue and add a simple runnable code

Comment: check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69048112/exported-kivy-python-code-to-android-and-pictures-wont-display-on-phone

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.