# Exported kivy/python code to android and pictures wont display on phone

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

I used buildozer to make my kivy/python code into an app on android, and I had pictures in the code that pointed to local places on my pc.  When I open the app they didn't display.  So I added the photos to the file directory in the ubuntu cmd prompt via Filezilla and I think it took the images but is still not displaying them.  What am i doing wrong?

Example of one part of the code:

```
Image:
    source: r"C:\Users\16783\Desktop\Protocols app\pics\Meds\Dekalbprotocols (1)-193.jpg"
    allow_stretch: False
    keep_ratio: False

    size_hint: 1, 1
GridLayout
    cols: 2
    size_hint: 1, .1
    spacing: 180
    Button:
        text: "Home"
        size_hint_y: .3
        on_press: root.manager.current = "HomePage"
        background_color: 0,0,0,1
    Button:
        text: "Back"
        size_hint_y: .3
        pos_hint: {"right": 1}
        on_press: root.manager.current = "MedsPage"
        background_color: 0,0,0,1
```

Answer (score 1):

**firstly**,make sure that the images path is just it's name and put all images in the same directory of buildozer

**secod thing**, make sure that you include the images extension in buildozer.spec file, or let it empty and put the images in the same directory of main file